# Clean architecture Maven module dependency

Tags: maven, architecture, dependencies, clean-architecture

I have a project designed by clean architecture with Maven tool .

My entry point module(E) has dependency on next level which is bridge(BR) between use-case(UC) module and E module. That BR module has dependency on UC module which mean that UC is visible for E too . Can I change something in `pom.xml` of moduleS so that the E will not see UC but will see BR module which is seeing UC?

In other words I have something like this:

E <isDependentOn> BR <isDependentOn> UC ? How To hide UC from E ?

I wrote the theoretical question as I can't share my codes regarding to policy of project.

Comment: Can you please explain that way more ditailed ? 
Also maybe other tool is good for C-A ?

Comment: (mixed up in prev comment, so a retry) You have something like E <isDependentOn> BR <isDependentOn> UC ? To hide UC from E would be possible only -afaik- by setting scope of UC to `provided` in BR pom. Otherwise this seems a bit like few concepts are mixed up or then maven is not suitable tool for C-A. I am not capable to tell another tool hope someone else is if it is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [POM Reference – Exclusions](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Exclusions):

> Exclusions explicitly tell Maven that you don't want to include the specified project that is a dependency of this dependency (in other words, its transitive dependency). For example, the [`BR`] requires [`UC`], and we do not wish to use it or its dependencies, then we would add it as an `exclusion`.

So you have BR as dependency in E. In the latter you declare UC as `<exclusion>` in BR's `<dependency>` declaration.

Comment: Of course. I understood that the dependency should not be even visible to the Es pom so not even excludable in it. Good if this satisfies C-A.